# (LARAVEL) Get a record with paginated list of records from a relating table (1 to many)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pagination

Let us consider a simple example: A **tag** has numerous number of **questions** (i.e. 1 to many relation). So, what I wanted is to get a tag record along with the paginated list of message records inside of it.

For this what I have done is:

```
function getTagWithQuestions(Request $request, $tagId)
{
    // get tag
    $tag = Tag::find($tagId);
    // check if it exists or not
    if (!isset($tag->id)) {
        return response(['message' => 'Tag not found'], 404);
    }
    // get paginated list of questions
    $questions = Question::where(['tag_id' => $tag->id])->paginate();
    // assign questions to tag
    $tag->questions = QuestionResource::collection($questions);

    // return the contents
    return new TagResource($tag);
}
```

The result i needed should have to be in this format:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "javascript",
    "questions": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "data": [...(list of questions)],
        "first_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/uv1/tags/8?page=1",
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "last_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/uv1/tags/8?page=1",
        "next_page_url": null,
        "path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/uv1/tags/8",
        "per_page": "15",
        "prev_page_url": null,
        "to": 5,
        "total": 5
    }
}
```

But somehow the result I got was a non-paginated list of contacts array.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "javascript",
    "questions": [...(list of questions)]
}
```

Is there any way to get this same output(as I need the pagination meta to append paginations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `$questions` to array, the structure will be what you want,

```php
$questions = Question::where(['tag_id' => $tag->id])->paginate();
// assign questions to tag
$tag->questions = $questions->toAarray();

// return the contents
return new TagResource($tag);
```

Remember don't use `with('questions')`, or you need to assign to another key, like so:

```php
$tag->questions_list = $questions->toAarray();
```

Comment: Whoa, you're a life saver, Thanks a lot